# View pdf on a asp.net page

Tags: .net, asp.net, pdf

I need a secure way to display pdf documents so that the viewer can't print, copy or save the text. Something like the amazon book preview. It will be placed on a asp.net page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Ghostscript (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/GhostScriptUseWithCSharp.aspx) to convert the PDFs individual pages into images for display. This would prevent them from being able to download the whole PDF document or copy the text as text. You could also add a watermark or use a lower resolution image. However, even with the amazon viewer you can always grab the image e.g. via screenshot.